# Getting the cheapest prices in Google's qpx-express API

Tags: google-api, google-qpx-express-api

I'm sending the following request to https://www.googleapis.com/qpxExpress/v1/trips/search?key=[mykey]

```
{
    "request": {
        "passengers": {
            "adultCount": 1
        },
        "slice": [{
            "origin": "JFK",
            "destination": "PDX",
            "date": "2017-04-21",
            "maxStops": 20
        }],
        "solutions": 500
    }
}
```

I get a valid response.  However, the cheapest price I see in the response is consistently a great deal higher than that which Google's GUI delivers:

Cheapest price in JSON response:

- `response.trips.tripOption[0].saleTotal`
- Cheapest price: "USD421.80"

Cheapest price in Google's app:

- https://www.google.com/flights/#search;f=JFK;t=PDX;d=2017-04-21;r=2017-04-25;tt=o
- https://screencast.com/t/r9A4cZTjE64
- Cheapest price: $230

Can anyone spot a way I could improve my request body, in order to acquire the cheaper options?  It may just be that Google doesn't surface all options in their API, but this seems a bit strange to me.

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the saleTotal in this location:

```
dat['trips']['tripOption'][0]['pricing'][0]['saleTotal']
```

Hope it helps

Comment: There is no reason that the sale price would be different in the `pricing` tree of the result.

Comment: Have a look it can be